# flatlist rendering duplicate array from firestore

Tags: arrays, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I'm pulling data from firestore into a flat list. For some reason my array from firestore is rendering twice. Has anyone run into this issue before?

```
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
var reviews = [];
let that = this;
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
const { user, review, image} = doc.data();
reviews.push({
  key: doc.id,
  user: doc.data().user,
  review: doc.data().review, 
  image: doc.data().image, 
    });
  });
  that.setState({ 
  reviews,
  loading: false,
  });
}
```

My render function is below.

```
_renderItem(reviews){
console.log(reviews);
<View style={{height: 60, marginRight: 0, marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Avatar
                small
                rounded
                source={{uri: reviews.item.image}}
                activeOpacity={0.7}
              />
          </View>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 5, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Text>
              {reviews.item.user}
              </Text>
              <ReadMore
                  numberOfLines={1}
                  renderRevealedFooter={this._renderRevealedFooter}>
                  <Text>                       
                  {reviews.item.review}
                  </Text>
              </ReadMore>
          </View>
 </View>

  }
```

My flat list is

```
<FlatList 
  data={this.state.reviews}     
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. I needed to created a variable for reviews and link it to this.state first. I was duplicated it when i created an empty variable. Simply putting down

```
var reviews = this.state.reviews
```

cleared up the issue